# GCP Channel notification princing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a GCP project A witch uses Cloud monitoring, alerts and a channel notification to pubsub. My pubsub topic is in another project B.

Is there any cost in my project A relative to publish a msg in project B or relative to channel notification? Maybe a cost because that traffic between projects?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are billed on the project requested that contains the requested resource.

- The project that is billed for publishing is the project that contains the topic.
- The project that is billed for subscribing is the project that contains the subscription.

I believe it's better explained in this [description](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing#cross_project_billing):

> For example, if the subscription lives in project A, then project A is billed for data that is pulled from the subscription, even if the subscription is attached to a topic in project B.
>
> If an authorized service account in project A consumes messages from a subscription in project B, then project B is billed for the data that is pulled from the subscription.